# Best way to fill an array with elements from another array, scala

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming

I got two array of characters, looking like this:

> a, b, c, d, e, f, g
>
> k, e, y

and im need to associate each element from first array to elements from second, like this:

> a->k,
>
> b->e,
>
> c->y,
>
> d->k,
>
> e->e,
>
> f->y,
>
> g->k

but dont know how to implement this in functional style. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could zip the first `Array` with a continuous `Stream` :

```
scala> val a1 = Array('a,'b,'c,'d,'e,'f,'g)
a1: Array[Symbol] = Array('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g)

scala> val a2 = Array('k,'e,'y)
a2: Array[Symbol] = Array('k, 'e, 'y)

scala> val a3 = a1 zip (Stream.continually(a2).flatten)
a3: Array[(Symbol, Symbol)] = Array(('a,'k), ('b,'e), ('c,'y), ('d,'k),
                                    ('e,'e), ('f,'y), ('g,'k))
```

Comment: Or `Map(a1.zip(Stream.continually(a2).flatten):_*)` in case the OP wants a `Map` from elements of `a1` to elements of `a2`. (It's not quite clear from the question.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry for that. Il just want to get array, that look like values collection in that answer. Already solved.